# Matplotlib randomly ignores passed parameters at each execution

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I found a really strange behaviour of Matplotlib. I written a little script which reproduces this issue, please check [this gist repository](https://gist.github.com/marekyggdrasil/f324e8bc653896a5e1bccbef4d31e0e8#file-plottest-py) for the file.

### Description of the problem

The file referenced in the gist makes two 3D histogram plots. Each of those plots consists of nested bars (a bar inside of bar), they differ with edge colors, size and transparency (alpha).

What I find strange is, running this script multiple times produces different plot at each run. The script accepts an argument for modifying a file name, I run it in following way

```
$ python plottest.py a
$ python plottest.py b
$ python plottest.py c
$ python plottest.py c
$ python plottest.py c
```

(the `c` plot I had to run three times until figure became different than at `b` run)

and it led to following plots, exactly the same script created those three plots

[image: first run]
[image: second run]
[image: third run]

sometimes the `alpha` parameter is ignored (leading to lack of transparency), sometimes `edgecolor` parameter is ignored (leading to lack of black edges on the outer bars).

### Question

I find it hard to implement a reliable script if each time I run it, it leads to different plot. This is not a Jupyter notebook, it is just a regular Python script. I tried to remove `__pycache__` directory with no effect, parameters are still randomly ignored.

I think I am doing something wrong, there is something I don't understand in the way Matplotlib is drawing those axes leading to this behaviour. Maybe someone more experienced could comment on that.

### My environment

My operating system is

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.5
BuildVersion:   18F132
```

My Python version

```
$ python -V
Python 3.5.3
```

My Matplotlib version

```
$ pip show matplotlib
Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.0.3
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: http://matplotlib.org
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
License: PSF
Location: /Users/marek/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: kiwisolver, numpy, python-dateutil, pyparsing, cycler
Required-by: seaborn, scikit-image, chemview, chemlab
```

Comment: I can reproduce this with Python 3.5.3 and Matplotlib 3.0.3, but not with Python 3.7.5 and Matplotlib 3.1.2. Note that Matplotlib 3.0.3 appears to be most recent version that supports Python 3.5.3, so if there was a bug in Matplotlib 3.0 causing this, you can't upgrade to 3.1 unless you also upgrade your Python version (or try and compile current Matplotlib from source).

Comment: That is very interesting! Given my current setup it is not very safe to switch to Python 3.7, I'm too worried I might break my `pyenv` but as soon as I finish critical task I'm in the middle of, I will try your suggestion and give feedback. Thanks for your input and for reproducing this strange behaviour.

Comment: Pyenv should easily allow you to switch to 3.7 or 3.8 (and back); I actually used pyenv to try this on 3.5. Perhaps if you were developing for other people that only have access to 3.5, but otherwise, I see no reason to not upgrade (I guess some packages; chemview and chemlab are unknown packages which perhaps don't support 3.6+?).

Comment: But you should really be able to try: 3.7 or 3.8 will be completely independent from 3.5 when using pyenv (in particular if you install packages with e.g. `python -m pip install <xyz>`, so you're guaranteed to use the correct `pip`; though Pyenv should also take care of that).

Comment: I made the update, took a while because I had to modify buildscript for tcl-tk but now it works. I re-run the script ten times with matplotlib `3.1.2` and python `3.7.4` and outcome was identical. If you @00 write a solution to this question consisting of update of matplotlib and python and explain you reproduced the error and explanation should be bug in matplotlib I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@00 reproduced this problem and noticed it doesn't persist for newer versions of Python and Matplotlib. I made an update to

```
$ python -V
Python 3.7.4
```

and

```
$ pip show matplotlib
Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.1.2
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: https://matplotlib.org
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
License: PSF
Location: /Users/marek/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: cycler, python-dateutil, kiwisolver, pyparsing, numpy
Required-by:
```

Now no matter how many times I run the script outcome is identical and thus behaviour is predictible. Thanks for help!